# How would I assign this variable?

Tags: python, variables

I barely started this python tutorial and I don't understand how I would set this variable(total)

[image]

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: It should look pretty similar to the previous line. If you don't understand what it's doing, review the course material. This is a fundamental concept that you will need to know.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it this way: Your Variable meal now stores two meals plus the tax for both of them. The only thing that is missing is the tip.

Now you can create this

```
total = meal + tip
```

if meal or tip is changing, the result of total would change too. But you need to be careful to not get confused with this behaviour.

Variables are bound to their object content if you assign them directly like

```
variable = 1234
```

if you now got another variable that stores the same content you would (normally) not write this again:

```
vari2 = 1234
```

but instead:

```
vari2 = variable
```

The interesting about that is, if you print

```
print variable
print vari2
```

you get the same results as expected. But if you change your first variable after all this code, there will be a difference! You can try to run this last code piece to understand what i mean:

```
vari = 1234 #Integer variable
print "Vari: %r" % vari
varia = vari #The Variable varia is bound to the CONTENT of vari not to the Name vari!
print "varia from vari: %r\n... -> New vari " % (varia)
vari = 42 # Now if you change vari, the content of varia is still the same!
print "Varia %r from vari %r" % (varia, vari)
```

This behaviour is very useful to store the original starting value of a variable. So you can keep track how the variable changed over time.
I suggest to play a little with variables and print to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You have already used the same concept in the previous lines.

```
total = meal + (meal * tax)
```